# grouping results in a view ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2. I have 2 models and a viewmodel which injects data to a view. **I want to order results based on their productType**. Let's make it clear

This is **Product** model

```
public class Product
{
     public int ProductID { get; set; }
     public int ProductName { get; set; }
     public string ProductImage { get; set; }
     public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("ProductTypeID")]
     public virtual ProductType ProductType{ get; set; }
 }
```

This is **ProductType** model

```
public class ProductType
{
    public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeName { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeImage { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeDescription { get; set; 
}
```

And finally this is **DishesViewModel**

```
public class DishesVM
{
     public IEnumerable<ProductType> ProductType { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Product> Product { get; set; }
}
```

In **MyController** I get data from DB then with automapper, map them to DishViewModel

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Dishes()
    {
        var productTypes= _context.ProductType.OrderBy(p =>p.ProductTypeID).ToList();
        var products= _context.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductID).ToList();

        var DishesVM = new DishesVM();
            DishesVM.ProductType = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductType>>(productTypes);
            DishesVM.Product = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Product>>(products);
    }
}
```

Now in **Dishes** View I can have nested *foreach*

```
@model DishesViewModel
<div>
   foreach(var pt in Model.ProductType)
   {
      <h1>pt.ProductTypeName</h1>
      foreach(var p in Model.Product)
      {
        p.ProductName
      }
   }
</div>
```

This works fine but the only problem it has, is it returns all products. but I want each Product Category has its Products In front of its header. This is visual representation of what I want and what I have now.

This is **what I want**
[image: what I want]

But this is **what I have**
 [image: what I have]

Comment: Entity Framework is an ORM, not a view renderer. It generates and executes SQL statements, it doesn't nest or group table entries. What you ask is how to group different items in the view.

Comment: You can group the Products by type using LINQ and then iterate over the group to generate the "outer" row. After that, you can emit a *new* table, div or whatever element you like to display individual product items

Comment: Yes exactly. So what do u suggest changing title to " how to group different items in the view."?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i'm not familar with LINQ. post ur answer and i will try that. tnx

Comment: Just apply filtering: `foreach(var p in Model.Product.Where(x => x.ProductTypeID == pt.ProductTypeID))`

Comment: @RomanKoliada it's manual. If admin adds another ProductType. I should do it manual. it's not  dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter your products by product type in each iteration. At the moment you just display all products for each product type:

```
<div>
   foreach(var type in Model.ProductType)
   {
      //products which belong to the particular type
      var productsForType = Model.Product.Where(x => x.ProductTypeID == type.ProductTypeID);

      <h1>pt.ProductTypeName</h1>
      foreach(var product in productsForType)
      {
           product.ProductName
      }
   }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a jump on the linq statement:

```
var list = productTypes.Where(x => x.ProductTypeID == 1).Select(x => new Product()
        {
            ProductImage = x.ProductTypeImage,

        }).ToList();
```

You will need to decide on what to put into the where clause, I'm using ProductTypeID